# Left join in SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables
Table Room with columns- rid, rname, type,
Table Customer with columns- cid, cname,
Table Booking with columns- bid, cid, rid, check-in, check-out.

Now I have to get all the room names and if the room is book on 2019-09-01 then display the customer name in front of the room other wise show null.

I tried to apply a left join and where condition but its only giving me those room names which are booked on that day its not showing other room name.

```
select rname, c.cname from room as r
left join booking as b on b.rid=r.rid
left join customer as c on c.cid=b.cid
where b.[check-in]='2019-09-01'
```

and if I'm applying other condition its giving me addition name of the those room which are completely null, means they are not booked at all on any date.

```
select rname, c.cname from room as r
left join booking as b on b.rid=r.rid
left join customer as c on c.cid=b.cid
where b.[check-in]='2019-09-01' or b.[check-in] is null;
```

Comment: Move the `WHERE` in your first query to the `ON`. If you reference a column in the `WHERE` which is in a table you performed an `OUTER JOIN` to, you will turn it into an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I know you already got this working but I thought I'd offer a bit of insight into why it failed. Imagine that a room had other check-ins but none for September 1st. The join works ok at first until you apply the filter. Since neither condition matches that room disappears. Incorporating the additional logic into the join condition narrows the scope of the outer join to a smaller set of rows *before* the left join is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the b condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
select rname, c.cname from room as r
left join booking as b on b.rid=r.rid and b.[check-in]='2019-09-01'
left join customer as c on c.cid=b.cid
```